# Obtaining visible text on a page from an IHTMLDocument2*

Tags: c++, winapi, html-parsing, ole, mshtml

I am trying to obtain the text content of a Internet Explorer web browser window.

I am following these steps:

1. obtain a pointer to IHTMLDocument2
2. from the IHTMLDocument2 i obtain the body as an IHTMLElement
    <strike>3. On the body i call get_innerText</strike>

Edit

---

1. I obtain all the children of the body and try to do a recursive call on all the IHTMLElements
2. if i get any element which is not visible or if i get an element whose tag is script, i ignore that element and all its children.

My problem is

1. that along with the text which is visible on the page i also get content having for which  **style="display: none"**
2. For google.com, i also get javascript along with the text.

I have tried a recursive approach, but i am clueless as to how to deal with scenarios like this,

```
<div>
Hello World 1
<div style="display: none">Hello world 2</div>
</div>
```

In this scenario i wont be able to get "Hello World 1"

Can anyone please help me out with the best way to obtain the text from an IHTMLDocument2*.
I am using C++ Win32, no MFC, ATL.

Thanks,
Ashish.

Comment: You will probably need to iterate (from last to first) IHTMLDocument2 elements, and remove the Nodes you don't need.

Comment: @kobik I have considered that approach, but sometimes the parent element may contain text which may not be enclosed within any html tag. Consider this for an example. `<div>Hello World 1<div>Hello World 2</div></div>` If i follow this approach i wont be able to get Hello World 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you iterate backwards on the `document.body.all` elements, you will always walk on the elements inside out. So you don't need to walk recursive yourself. the DOM will do that for you. e.g. (Code is in Delphi):

```
procedure Test();
var
  document, el: OleVariant;
  i: Integer;
begin
  document := CreateComObject(CLASS_HTMLDocument) as IDispatch;
  document.open;
  document.write('<div>Hello World 1<div style="display: none">Hello world 2<div>This DIV is also invisible</div></div></div>');
  document.close;
  for i := document.body.all.length - 1 downto 0 do // iterate backwards
  begin
    el := document.body.all.item(i);
    // filter the elements
    if (el.style.display = 'none') then
    begin
      el.removeNode(true);
    end;
  end;
  ShowMessage(document.body.innerText);
end;
```

---

**A Side Comment:** 
As for your scenario with the recursive approach:

```
<div>Hello World 1<div style="display: none">Hello world 2</div></div>
```

If e.g. our element is the first DIV, [`el.getAdjacentText('afterBegin')`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536427%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will return `"Hello World 1"`. So we can probably iterate forward on the elements and collect the `getAdjacentText('afterBegin')`, but this is a bit more difficult because we need to test the parents of each element for `el.currentStyle.display`.

Comment: In my case i am working on an already open instance of IE, so is it recommended that i get the outerHTML of the body, and write it into some IHTMLDocument like you did in the example and then manipulate its DOM?

Comment: Yes, because this way you don't alter the DOM of the open instance of IE, and you can parse and abuse it all you want.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to map it to c++, and i think i have got it working. Also i would like to know the significance of iterating backwards.

Comment: We iterate backwards, because if we iterate forward and have e.g. 3 nested elements and remove element Index 1 (second element), the child element at Index 2 will be removed also. so when the loop Index reaches 2, `body.all.item(2)` was removed, and an exception will be raised.